# Updating main window title after exec gets segment fault

Tags: c++, windows, qt

If I call MainWindow function setWindowTitle after a.exec() is called in main.cpp I get a segment fault (C000 0005). Is there any way to change the window title after the gui is running. I don't believe this is a WIN 10 restriction as I could do this in python with tkinter. I am using qtcreator, but without QML forms.

Comment: You have an error in the code. Absolutely, we can set the window title any time we want if the code is correct.

Comment: When `exec()` returns, the GUI is done running, and you should be exiting the `main` function. You need to set the window title either while the application is running, or before the window is shown. But that's just to clear your misunderstanding of how `exec()` is to be used. Doing `setWindowTitle` after `exec()` returns is pointless, since the main window will be hidden at this point (the user had closed it to exit the application), but changing its name won't hurt. So please show the code that causes this issue. It's not usual.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by my trying to use a pointer to my main window withing a MainWindow function. Actually it was a bit more convoluted as I was actually calling a function in another class. The solution was to pass the this pointer to the function in the other class.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely trying to use a destroyed instance of `MainWindow`. Probably you mistakenly set the `QT_WADeleteOnClose` attribute on the window. The following self-contained example demonstrates this issue. The attribute may be set in the `.ui` file, and you may be unaware of it.

[image: screenshot of the example application]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/mainwindow-crash-double-delete-58305305
#include <QtWidgets>

class Window : public QMainWindow {
   QWidget central;
   QGridLayout layout{&central};
   QLabel label{"Hello, World!"};
   QCheckBox crash{"Crash on exit"};
public:
   static bool alive;
   Window() {
      alive = true;
      layout.addWidget(&label, 0, 0);
      layout.addWidget(&crash, 1, 0);
      setCentralWidget(&central);
      connect(&crash, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, [this](){
         setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, crash.isChecked());
      });
   }
   ~Window() {
      qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
      alive = false;
   }
};
bool Window::alive;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   int rc;
   {
      Window w;
      w.show();
      rc = a.exec();
      Q_ASSERT(w.alive);
      w.setWindowTitle("A New Title Awaits");
      qDebug() << "We're past w.setWindowTitle()";
   }
   return rc;
}
```